# Generate every Saturday of week date based on date supplied to query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a requirement to get every Saturday of week for dates given in dataset.
I want output like below.

Example:

```
ResolvedDate     Saturday of this week 

9/9/2019         9/14/2019
8/19/2018        8/24/2019 
9/4/2019         9/7/2019
```

Could some one please help me with this?

Comment: Column ResolvedDate data type?

Comment: SQL Server is Database .

Comment: @jarlh - Data type is date time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your

```
SELECT @@DATEFIRST
```

Returns 7

```
select  ResolvedDate,
        Convert(date, Dateadd(dd, 7-datepart(dw, ResolvedDate), ResolvedDate)) as [Saturday of this week]
From mytable;
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

for oracle:

```
select trunc(sysdate) + 6 - to_char(trunc(sysdate), 'D') as NextSaturday from dual
```

replace sysdate with your given date

Comment: How to do this in SQL Server ?